# how to build mozilla tamarin (AVM3) for android on windows?

Tags: android, windows, actionscript-3, mozilla

i am trying to embed avm3 into an android game engine, and the "Tamarin build documentation" is a little foggy about building it with cygwin in windows.

if someone actually has tried that with success, than please list me the required steps in details.                        thank you

Comment: It is not "Mozilla Tamarin" - Tamarin is Adobe's JavaScript/ActionScript engine contributed to Mozilla. Mozilla then incorporated parts of it into SpiderMonkey and moved on. Do you really need ActionScript or will "normal" JavaScript do as well?

Comment: my question is how to build Tamarin ActionScript Engine on windows.  and for JavaScript I'm already using Google V8

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at redtamarin it could be usefful

http://code.google.com/p/redtamarin/wiki/GettingStarted